# Tableau use SQL stored procedure to perform calculation - no equivalent in PowerBI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, tableau-desktop

I am trying to migrate a dashboard from Tableau to PowerBI.

In tableau desktop version 2021.2.8 64-bit, Analysis -> Calculated Field, I can create a calculation, to call a stored procedure in the SQL Server. I trigger a stored procedure to calculate the Internal Rate of Return, using a series of cashflow as input.

In the PowerBI report server May 2022 version, I tried to perform a similar feature. The stored procedure is already in my SQL Server. (Note: my version doesn't have a dynamic M query parameter) Is there any way I can call my stored procedure in PowerBI?

Please note, the key issue is that user input would be required as a parameter of the stored procedure. (I can run my stored procedure only by hardcode all parameters, but cannot be based on user input.) Thanks.

Comment: My SQL server is SSMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: SSRS != PowerBI. Which one are you using?

Comment: Edited. I am using PowerBI, not SSRS.

Comment: Short answer: Power BI doesn't work with stored procedures. BUT if you use "Paginated Reports" (which is basically SSRS inside Power BI) then they do work